# MariaDB/Mysql Left join not working as expected

Tags: mysql, left-join

`select count(*) from devices` -> returns number 241

`select count(*) from address_devices` -> returns number 200

```
select d.DeviceID,adl.DeviceID
from devices d
left join (
    select ad.* from address_devices ad
    where ad.id in (
            SELECT max(sad.id) as max_id
            from address_devices sad 
            group by sad.DeviceID
    ) 
) as adl
on d.DeviceID = adl.DeviceID
```

I would expect the SQL query to return 241 rows but it returns only 137.

Is there anything I'm missing? I would assume that even if the `adl.DeviceID` is `null` it would nevertheless show up the record on the devices table left join

Comment: Have you used php-myadmin to comfirm. If so, I think this is a php-myadmin issue, not My SQL issue. Please recheck it with other MySQL client other than php-myadmin

Comment: Try select count(distinct DeviceID) from devices to see how many you have

Comment: Your expectation is valid. Unless you can provide sample data with which this can be reproduced, I'd assume you just confused different results with the appropriate query or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
select d.DeviceID,adl.DeviceID,
(select * from address_devices ad
    where ad.id in (
            SELECT max(sad.id) as max_id
            from address_devices sad 
            group by sad.DeviceID
    ) 
) as adl from devices d left join address_devices ad1
on d.DeviceID = adl.DeviceID
```